# Bad Integer 2147483649 (its BIGINT value) error in Postgres

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, hilo

I m using hibernate 3 with hilo key generator and Postgres 9.3.Table column is BIGINT and model class variable is long(java).

From back-end no issue but when i try to save from front-end console are showing Bad Integer '2147483649' error.
 Table schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE user_log
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  appuser_id bigint,
  user_role_id bigint,
  login_time timestamp without time zone,
  logout_time timestamp without time zone,
  logged_in_ip character varying(32),
  CONSTRAINT user_log_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_app_user FOREIGN KEY (appuser_id)
      REFERENCES app_user (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_user_role FOREIGN KEY (user_role_id)
      REFERENCES user_role (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Model class:

```
public class UserLog extends ModelBase {

/** identifier field */
private Long id;

/** persistent field */
private AppUser user;

/** nullable persistent field */
private Date loginTime;

/** nullable persistent field */
private Date logoutTime;

/** nullable persistent field */
private UserRole loggedInRole;

/** nullable persistent field */
private String loggedInIP;

/**
 * @hibernate.id generator-class="hilo"  column="id"
 * 
 */
public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/**
 * @hibernate.many-to-one
 * @hibernate.column name="user_role_id"
 * 
 */
public UserRole getLoggedInRole() {
    return loggedInRole;
}

public void setLoggedInRole(UserRole loggedInRole) {
    this.loggedInRole = loggedInRole;
}

/**
 * @hibernate.property column="login_time" type="java.util.Date"
 * 
 */
public Date getLoginTime() {
    return loginTime;
}

public void setLoginTime(Date loginTime) {
    this.loginTime = loginTime;
}

/**
 * @hibernate.property column="logout_time" type="java.util.Date"
 * 
 */
public Date getLogoutTime() {
    return logoutTime;
}

public void setLogoutTime(Date logoutTime) {
    this.logoutTime = logoutTime;
}

/**
 * @hibernate.many-to-one
 * @hibernate.column name="appuser_id"
 * 
 */
public AppUser getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(AppUser user) {
    this.user = user;
}

/**
 * @hibernate.property column="logged_in_IP" length="32"
 * 
 */
public String getLoggedInIP() {
    return loggedInIP;
}

public void setLoggedInIP(String loggedInIP) {
    this.loggedInIP = loggedInIP;
}
```

}

Error stack trace:

```
 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad Integer 2147483649
    at org.postgresql.jdbc1.AbstractJdbc1ResultSet.toInt(AbstractJdbc1ResultSet.java:857)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc1.AbstractJdbc1ResultSet.getInt(AbstractJdbc1ResultSet.java:282)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getInt(DelegatingResultSet.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.id.TableGenerator.doWorkInCurrentTransaction(TableGenerator.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.engine.TransactionHelper$1Work.doWork(TransactionHelper.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.Isolater$JdbcDelegate.delegateWork(Isolater.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.Isolater.doIsolatedWork(Isolater.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.engine.TransactionHelper.doWorkInNewTransaction(TransactionHelper.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.id.TableGenerator.generate(TableGenerator.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.id.TableHiLoGenerator.generate(TableHiLoGenerator.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:33)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:535)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:523)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:519)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:541)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:312)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.save(HibernateTemplate.java:538)
    at com.dimensionsgroup.campus.core.dao.impl.CampusDaoSupport.create(CampusDaoSupport.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:288)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:155)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:122)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:144)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:144)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:174)
    at $Proxy9.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.dimensionsgroup.campus.common.action.LoginAction.go(LoginAction.java:137)
    at com.dimensionsgroup.campus.common.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:113)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:168)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.intercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:55)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:165)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork.interceptor.AroundInterceptor.intercept(AroundInterceptor.java:35)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:165)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork.interceptor.AroundInterceptor.intercept(AroundInterceptor.java:35)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:165)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork.interceptor.AroundInterceptor.intercept(AroundInterceptor.java:35)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:165)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork.interceptor.AroundInterceptor.intercept(AroundInterceptor.java:35)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:165)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork.interceptor.AroundInterceptor.intercept(AroundInterceptor.java:35)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:165)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork.DefaultActionProxy.execute(DefaultActionProxy.java:115)
    at com.opensymphony.webwork.dispatcher.ServletDispatcher.serviceAction(ServletDispatcher.java:272)
    at com.opensymphony.webwork.dispatcher.ServletDispatcher.service(ServletDispatcher.java:237)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:879)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: From the error it seems the front end might be using Integer as the datatype and its value is exceeding those of int datattype.
Minimum value is - 2,147,483,648.(-2^31) Maximum value is 2,147,483,647(inclusive).(2^31 -1).

Comment: I know that but  why using as a Integer while i am using bigint.

Comment: add your error stack trace

Comment: I did modified id int to bigint. In starting it was integer  in table as well as model class,

Comment: Try changing Long to BigInteger.

Answer (score 0):

The error happens when Hibernate tries to create a new id for the `user_log` table.

In your app Hibernate uses `org.hibernate.id.TableGenerator` to generate Ids which in turn wants to return a integer. This leads to the exception since the next available id is bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Seems that you are using a Hibernate version < 3.5 since the [Javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/id/TableGenerator.html) says:

> Again, the return types supported here are any of the ones supported
>   by IntegralDataTypeHolder. This is new as of 3.5. Prior to that this
>   generator only returned Integer values.

So even if you used the right datatypes in your table and in your POJO the TableGenerator can only return integers, unless you update to a newer Hibernate version.

Comment: As per my current debugging i fount that problem with hibernate_unique_key table its not taking  greater than value of integer.

Comment: As per my current debugging i fount that problem with hibernate_unique_key table, its not taking  value which greater from integer. When hibernate found BIGINT value in "hibernate_unique_key" (next_hi) it throw error Bad Integer . I think internal manipulation for key generation is running with Integer parameters.But i dont know how to change this.

Answer (score 0):

after changing hibernate version 3.0 to 3.2 problem solved.